# Trimming text to minimal unique length

Tags: r

I have a vector of unique names that I'd like to trim. I want each item in the vector to be the smallest possible length that still allows it to be unique. My real data has entries that are quite long.

Here's my minimal reproducible example.

```
flavors <- c("Apple mango", "Apple", "Cherry", "Cranberry", "Cran raspberry")
```

I've removed all spaces.

```
flavor <- stringr::str_replace_all(flavors, " ", "")
```

I'd like the result to be a vector that looks something like this.

```
c("Applem", "Apple", "Cherry", "Cranb", "Cranr")
```

Any ideas? In my real dataset, this vector is a column being used in a machine learning model. Would I be better of using a hashing algorithm with a lookup table? I'm open to ideas.

Comment: Why the length constraint? If you're open to hashing, why not just assign a sequential primary key with a lookup table?

Comment: `df1 <- data.frame(flavors = c("Apple mango", "Apple", "Cherry", "Cranberry", "Cran raspberry"), ID = seq(1,5))`

Comment: Assuming you have a big table, you'd just find `unique(flavors)`, and construct `data.frame(flavors = unique(flavors), ID = seq(1,length(unique(flavors))))`

Comment: why do "Apple" and "Cherry" stay as is rather than shortening to "A" and "C"?

Comment: @J.Win. I think the OP is asking for a minimal unambiguous prefix. "A" would be ambiguous, as it could refer to "Apple mango" or "Apple".

Comment: @Andrew and if I'm right, then [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is the concept you're looking for. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any implementations in R.

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka if that were the case, "Ch" would still be correct... I went with a different assumption

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to obtain unique values you can make use of the `digest` function available through the [`digest`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=digest) package.

```
flavors <-
    c("Apple mango", "Apple", "Cherry", "Cranberry", "Cran raspberry")

vf <- Vectorize(FUN = digest::digest,
                vectorize.args = "object")

vf(object = flavors, algo = "crc32")
```

This would produce the following results:

```
vf(object = flavors, algo = "crc32")
   Apple mango          Apple         Cherry      Cranberry Cran raspberry 
    "b8bd7ce5"     "f3bbf1aa"     "95671d86"     "b3e2a7b8"     "65abba84"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite have the result you're looking for but this is close and unique.  I just doesn't take Cranbe and Cranre to Cranb and Cranr.  It is also not very elegant (loops).

```
maxLength <- max(unlist(lapply(X = flavor,FUN = str_length)))
stop <- FALSE
i <- 0
while (stop == FALSE) {
  i <- i + 1
  if (length(unique(substr(x = flavor,start = 1,stop = i))) == length(unique(flavor))) stop = TRUE
}
substr(x = flavor,start = 1,stop = i)
[1] "Applem" "Apple"  "Cherry" "Cranbe" "Cranra"
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some notion of not cutting anything below five characters, otherwise "Apple" would shorten to "A" and "Cherry" would shorten to "C".  Therefore...

```
flavors <- c("Apple mango", "Apple", "Cherry", "Cranberry", "Cran raspberry")
flavor <- unique(stringr::str_replace_all(flavors, " ", ""))
min_length = min(nchar(flavor))
done = FALSE

prune <- function(fruits) {
  longest <- which.max(nchar(fruits))
  str <- fruits[longest]
  matched <- FALSE
  while(matched == FALSE && nchar(str) > min_length ) {
    str <- gsub('.{1}$', '', str)
    if(!(str %in% fruits[-longest])) {
      fruits[longest] <- str
    } else {
      matched <- TRUE
    }
  }
  return(fruits)
}

while(!done) {
  new_flavor <- prune(flavor)
  if(identical(new_flavor, flavor)) {
    done <- TRUE
  } else {
    flavor <- new_flavor
  }
}

> flavor
[1] "Applem" "Apple"  "Cherry" "Cranb"  "Cranr"
```